# Hiding code when php field doesn't have value

Tags: php

I need to hide the code if a PHP field value is empty.

Here's the code:

```
<?php if( get_field('volunteer_causes') ): ?>   
                <div class="program-single-volunteer-causes">
                    <h4>Volunteer Causes</h4>
                    <?php
                    $terms = get_field('volunteer_causes');

                    if( $terms ): ?>

                        <ul>

                        <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>

                            <li>
                                <span><?php echo $term ?></span>
                            </li>

                        <?php endforeach; ?>

                        </ul>

                    <?php endif; ?>
                </div><!--program-single-volunteer-causes-->
```

As it is, if there's no value in the 'volunteer_causes' field then the HTML will remain.

I've tried using echo for each line containing the HTML.
Example: `<?php echo '<h4>Volunteer Causes</h4>'; ?>`
However, this changed nothing.

This method works to remove all code when there's no value present in the field:
 `<?php if( !empty(the_field('volunteer_causes')) ): ?>`
... however, my HTML is missing when the values do show up.

Comment: Also, what is `var_dump($terms);` when its populated and when its empty?

Answer (score 1):

You can shorten this by assigning in the `if` and you may have forgotten to close the first `if`:

```
<?php if( $terms = get_field('volunteer_causes') ): ?>   
    <div class="program-single-volunteer-causes">
        <h4>Volunteer Causes</h4>
            <ul>
            <?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>
                <li>
                    <span><?php echo $term ?></span>
                </li>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </ul>
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this did not work. The HTML still shows even when the field is empty. Thanks for your efforts.

Comment: Then the field is not really empty.That's why I commented _what is `var_dump($terms);` when its populated and when its empty?_

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
<div class="program-single-volunteer-causes">
  <?php

   $terms = get_field('volunteer_causes');

   if (!empty($terms)) {
    echo
     '<h4>Volunteer Causes</h4>
     <ul>';
     foreach ($terms as $term) {
      echo
       '<li><span>' . $term . '</span></li>';
     }
     echo
     '</ul>';
   } else {
     echo '<p>No Record Found</p>';
   } 
 ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Code looks like it should work. However, no luck. The HTML is still showing even when the fields don't have values. Thanks for your efforts!

Answer (score -1):

I ended up paying someone $5 on a freelancer site to get it to work. This is what they came up with and it works!

```
<?php
$volunteer_causes = get_field('volunteer_causes');
if($volunteer_causes[0]){ ?>
<div class="program-single-volunteer-causes">
<h4>Volunteer Causes</h4>
<?php
$terms = get_field('volunteer_causes');

if( $terms ): ?>

<ul>

<?php foreach( $terms as $term ): ?>

<li>
<span><?php echo $term ?></span>
</li>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>

<?php endif;
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Could have saved $5 if you had shown a `var_dump()` like asked.